# Load n-number of stars from user (pieces to display - not rows)

Tags: c++, algorithm, console

I have following problem in C++:
Basiclly this code:

```
#include<iostream>   

using namespace std; 

int main() { 

int n=5;

for(int rows = 1; rows <= n; rows++){

for(int col = rows; col <= n; col++){

   cout << "*";

     }

cout << endl;

}

  return 0; 

}
```

Shows this output:

```
*****

****

***

**

*
```

When I added to the code input from user it doesn't work this is the code with input:

```
#include<iostream>   

using namespace std; 

int main() { 


while(n>0){

int n;

cin >> n;

for(int rows = 1; rows <= n; rows++){

for(int col = rows; col <= n; col++){

   cout << "*";

    n--;

     }

cout << endl;

   }

}        

  return 0; 

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I want get such a result for input n = 6:

```
***
**
*
```

for 5:

```
***
**
```

for 15:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

As you can see patterns basing on the numbers of stars not the num of rows.

Comment: Why is the output for n=5 3+2 stars instead of 2+2+1? Maybe start with something simpler: figure out how many rows you need for an input that makes up a "full" triangle. That allows you to go from number of stars to a number of rows. What you then to for incomplete triangles really depends on your assignment.

Comment: Your code is too compilcated. Do things in tiny simple steps. First do the maths on how many rows you need to print and whats the number of stars in the first row. Only then write the loops to iterate rows

Comment: `n--;` inside a loop that iterates till `n` is a no-go. Even if you could manage to make such a loop do the right thing, it will be too complicated. Code not only has to "do the right thing" but it also has to be readable and clear and simple

Comment: That's the problem, my task is not to about how many rows I need but to print stars till they re gone

Comment: So how would I check the num of stars without n-- and while loop?

Comment: Write one loop that calculates the number of stars on the first line, then a second loop that just fills rows until the stars are up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That's the problem, my task is not to about how many rows I need but to print stars till they re gone

*The problem* is that you think your task is not about how many rows to print, but it is. How else are you going to print some number of rows, when you do not know how many rows to print?

Rather than doing it all at once and starting with a loop to print the stars, you should first determine what to print. The total number of stars in this kind of pattern is

```
 #stars( #rows ) = ( #rows - 1) * #rows
```

For example, in 3 rows you have 3*2 = 6 stars. This is a quadratic equation that for given `#stars` you can solve for `#rows`. Alternatively, we know that adding a `n-th` row adds `n` more stars:

```
int num_stars_to_print;
std::cin >> num_stars_to_print;

int rows_to_print = 1;
int total_stars = 1;
while ( total_stars < num_stars_to_print ) {
      rows_to_print += 1; 
      total_stars  += rows_to_print;
}
```

After this loop you know how many rows you have to print: `rows_to_print`. The number of stars in this first row is `rows_to_print`. I'll leave it for you to actually print the stars.

Comment: print the stars by nested for loops or the other way?

Comment: @Carb0n what is "the other way" ? I suggest a loop for rows and then `std::cout << std::string(num_stars, '*') << '\n';` not the most efficient, but nice and simple (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for the constructor (2) I am using)

Comment: I'm more asking whether the loop for writing the stars should be nested in a while loop together with a loop counting how many rows there are.

Comment: @Carb0n you can print them any way you like. You already have code to print `n` rows where the first one has `n` stars. You can use that.

Comment: @Carb0n only to remove some stars at the end needs some modifications. For that you can count the number of stars you already printed and then skip some in the last row. I am not going to provide you the full code for your homework though, because that would steal you a chance to learn